# Nonclustered index include argument serving wider range of queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is for SQL Server 2012.

After creating

```
create nonclustered index [myindex_includes] 
on dbo.sampletable([personid] asc)
Include ([Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4], [Q5], [Q6], [Q7], [Q8], [Q9], [Q10], [Q11],[Q12])
```

I run SQL Server profiler and recommendations tell me to create another index that has fewer columns in the `include` i.e.

```
nonclustered index on personid 
include ([Q1], [Q4], [Q6], [Q9], [Q10])
```

Shouldn't that index be covering the query recommended by tuner? Is it necessary to create the 2nd index in any situation when I have index like first case?

Comment: Isn't your first index almost same size as whole table?

Comment: @IvanStarostin there are more columns but i'm not sure why tuner recommends to create another same index but with less include columns.?

Comment: I don't know. Can you show your query?

Answer (score 0):

The more columns you INCLUDE the more space (more pages) the leaf-level of your index will need. And the bigger an index is the more space it will need in memory and on disc (and backups). So SQL-Server may have to deal with more pages in order to return query results in comparison to a smaller index.

First you should check, if you really need all those columns in the index.

If some queries really need all those columns in the INCLUDE-List and others only need some of those columns, you should test if an extra smaller index gives you better SELECT performance. But more indexes decrease INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE-Performance.

If there is not a performance problem I would not add an extra index with fewer columns.